# How JetsonTX2 Nvidia gpu usage if there is two gpu required job running?

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, nvidia, nvidia-jetson

I want to know morw about the Nvidia gpu for the multi job running same time.

There is one job CNN object localization/detection using gpu , and another one object detection .

Both running same time and requires gpu power.

How the Nvidia JetsonTx2 and other 2080Txi for example sharing their resources ?

Is it possibble or we can only one gpu worker same time?